# Swift Framework built with New Build System not recognized by Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

When I integrate my Swift Framework into an Objective-C project, after using Xcode's New Build System, the project does not recognize the public class names and api from the framework.

I'm receiving a 'Use of undeclared identifier 'SampleClassName' error when I go to build the project.

I have updated my Swift 5 framework's build script to  use Xcode's new build system. The build script creates a fat binary that can be imported into any Xcode project (we provide a strip unused architectures run script) to remove the unused archs.

I have tried the following to resolve this issue with no luck:
- set Project Build Setting 'Defines Module' -> Yes
- I have tried explicitly stating which architectures to build for
- set 'Always embed Swift Standard Libraries' -> YES

This is the way I am defining our public class

```
open class SampleClassName: NSObject {

  // a public class definition within my framework
  @objc public static fun run() -> Bool { ... }

}
```

Our {ProjectName}.h file implementation

```
//! Project version number for SampleProject.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double SampleProjectVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for SampleProject.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char SampleProjectVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <SampleProject/PublicHeader.h>
```

Our {ProjectName}-Bridging-Header.h implementation

```
#include "SystemUtils.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

This is the ruby build script I use to create the fat binary.

```
#!/usr/bin ruby

require 'open3'
require 'optparse'
require 'plist'

PROJECT_DIR        = Dir.pwd
PROJECT_NAME       = 'SampleProject'

BUILD_DIR          = PROJECT_DIR+'/'+PROJECT_NAME
DERIVED_DATA       = 'DerivedData'
FRAMEWORK_NAME     = 'SampleProjectFramework'
OUTPUT_NAME        = 'SampleFramework'
UNIVERSAL_BUILD    = 'Release-universal'
WORKSPACE_DIR      = '..'

def run(command)
  puts command
  stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3(command)
  out = stdout.readlines
  puts out
  err = stderr.readlines
  [out.to_s, err.to_s]
end

def clean_build
  Dir.chdir("#{PROJECT_NAME}")
  run("rm -rf build")
  Dir.chdir("..")
end

def clean_deriveddata
  Dir.chdir("#{PROJECT_NAME}")
  run("rm -rf #{DERIVED_DATA}")
end

def create_universaldir
  Dir.chdir("#{BUILD_DIR}")
  run("mkdir #{DERIVED_DATA}")
  Dir.chdir("#{DERIVED_DATA}")
  run("mkdir #{UNIVERSAL_BUILD}")
  Dir.chdir("#{PROJECT_DIR}")
end

def create_ios(architecture)
  Dir.chdir("#{BUILD_DIR}")
  command = "xcodebuild -workspace SampleProject.xcworkspace -scheme #{FRAMEWORK_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration Release -sdk #{architecture} BUILD_DIR=#{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA} BUILD_ROOT=#{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA} -UseNewBuildSystem=YES OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS='-D RELEASE -D EXLUDE_PROXY -D NOIDFA' build"

  run(command)
  Dir.chdir('..')
end

def copy_structure
  run("cp -R #{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA}/Release-iphoneos/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework #{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA}/#{UNIVERSAL_BUILD}/")
end

def copy_swift_modules
  swift_simulator_modules_dir = "#{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA}/Release-iphonesimulator/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
  command =
  "if [ -d #{swift_simulator_modules_dir} ]; then
    cp -R #{swift_simulator_modules_dir} #{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA}/#{UNIVERSAL_BUILD}/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Modules/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.swiftmodule
  fi"
  run(command)
end

def create_universal_binary
  command = "lipo -create -output '#{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA}/#{UNIVERSAL_BUILD}/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}' '#{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA}/Release-iphonesimulator/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}' '#{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA}/Release-iphoneos/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}'"
  run(command)
end

def copy_to_project
  command = "cp -R '#{BUILD_DIR}/#{DERIVED_DATA}/#{UNIVERSAL_BUILD}/#{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework' '#{BUILD_DIR}'"
end

def put_title(message, sep = "-")
  total_message =  "#{(sep * 10)} #{message} #{(sep * 10)}"

  puts "\n\n\n"
  puts sep * total_message.length
  puts total_message
  puts sep * total_message.length
end


def main
  put_title 'Cleaning build'
  clean_build

  put_title 'Cleaning DerivedData'
  clean_deriveddata

  put_title 'Creating Universal Directory'
  create_universaldir

  put_title 'Creating iOS device version'
  create_ios('iphoneos')

  put_title 'Creating iOS simulator version'
  create_ios('iphonesimulator')

  put_title 'Copying framework structure to the Universal build'
  copy_structure

  put_title 'Copying Swift Modules'
  copy_swift_modules

  put_title 'Creating Universal Binary'
  create_universal_binary

 put_title 'Copy to project dir'
 copy_to_project
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  main
end
```

The main change that is now causing the 'Use of undeclared identifier error' is switching to the new build system.

I expect the public classes to be recognized by the Objective-C project files. Unfortunately, I do not know why they are not being recognized.

Comment: What I found was that you can create a swift file inside your Objc project that uses the framework, and that way it will work.

Comment: Hey Richard, have you found a solution for this issue?